# Attribute expansion substring, get a substring at the Nth occurence

Tags: bash, substring

Let's say I have a filename:

```
Filename=AB123_10_001_00202.jpg
```

Using as much as possible `bash` "attribute expansion substring" ,
I would like to extract "202" or in general the number without the "_00".

If I do:

```
Name=${Filename%.jpg}
```

I get:

```
AB123_10_001_00202
```

but then, as many "_0" occur, I don't see how to proceed.
So I tried:

```
Number=${Name##*_0}
```

...which works in case of the last digits are 12, 123 or 1234 for example.  But if a "_0" is in-between some digit like 202, I only get "2".

Comment: You might want to use `[[ string =~ regex ]]` with `BATCH_REMATCH` instead.

Comment: `if a 0 is in-between some digit like 202` No, it would have to be `_0` between some digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the leading zeroes is tricky using parameter expansion. You could remove them by interpreting the number:

```
Filename=AB123_10_001_00202.jpg
Name="${Filename%.jpg}"
PaddedNumber="${Name##*_}"
(( Number = "10#$PaddedNumber" ))
```

Alternatively, use bash's matching operator

```
Filename=AB123_10_001_00202.jpg
Regex='.*_0*([0-9]+)'
[[ "$Filename" =~ $Regex ]]
Number="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the one who posted this answer but removed it.

It worked perfectly well. Just in case someone get stuck as I was.

```
$ fname=AB123_10_001_00202.jpg

$ str=${fname%.jpg}
$ echo $fname
AB123_10_001_00202

$ shopt -s extglob
$ printf  -v var '%s\n' "${str##*_*(0)}"
$ echo $var
202
```

Comment: The user who posted and deleted this answer was @Inian.